# What could those shiny spots on the walnut kernels be?

Tags: species-identification, food, seeds, safety

I bought the shelled walnuts — many were mouldy — but those small round reflective spots don't look like mould (ascomycetes). It reminds more of *E.coli* colonies. I couldn't find anything on the net about that.

I would like to know how to isolate or stain that, since I have some access to the lab.

[image]

[image]